# How can I assign values in R using row numbers?

Tags: r

I have a data frame and I would like to assign a particular value (Say "water") to all elements with row numbers from 10-100 and column 5. I would do the same for another row range of 500-600 in the same column 5.

I can do this separately as I have to do it only 3-4 times. Please let me know how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be done with:

```
dat[c(10:100, 500:600), 5] = "water"
```

(Where `dat` is your data frame).

Comment: One quick question: When the column has numbers, I can access the element value directly. But in case of characters, I am getting "levels". How can I access character values directly? Thanks

Comment: @GeekunaMatata: This is because that column is a factor, not a character vector. You likely wish to change it to a character with `dat$columnName = as.character(dat$columnName)`